# React и верстка Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, reactjs

Есть компонент на React. Это блок новостей. Как сверстать это на Wordpress?

Т.е. сайт создан на React. Как его сверстать на Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [WP Reactivate](https://github.com/gopangolin/wp-reactivate/), например.